# Need to plot stacked Rank bar graph

Tags: r, sorting, ranking

I need to plot a stacked rank bar graph, in decreasing order like a sample attached graph. I have also linked my data ([data file](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/folders/1dNmGTI8_c9PK1QqmfIjnpbyzuiCXgxFC)) that is already ranked for three years - 2018, 2019, and with Existing_Year. I want to keep years on x-axis, and water-use on y-axis, and fill with sectors that can be shown in legend as well with colors.

I am trying this code but not working. I went through various similar questions on this platform but also didn't work.

My code:

```
rank_use%>%
ggplot(., aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(year)), y = water_use, fill = sectors)) + 
geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
theme_economist_white() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), axis.text = 
element_text(face= "bold"),legend.position = 'right') + 
labs(fill = "Sectors", face="bold")+ 
ylab('Water Use (Thousand m3)') + xlab("Year")+ ylim(0,50000)+
theme(text=element_text(size=10, family="Arial"))+
ggtitle("Top 10 sectors by water use for 2018, 2019, and with existing  year")+
theme(plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, face='bold'))+
theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")),
    plot.title = element_text(vjust = 3))+
theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold"))
```

[image: sample image]

I will appreciate your help with this,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set levels of `year` before you plot the graph.

Please notice that names of variable from data attatched are slightly different with your code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

rank_ind<- rank_use %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(Water_Use = sum(Water_Use)) %>% arrange(desc(Water_Use)) %>%
  pull(year)
rank_use%>%
  mutate(year = factor(year, levels = rank_ind)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = Water_Use, fill = sector)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  theme_economist_white() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), axis.text = 
                                    element_text(face= "bold"),legend.position = 'right') + 
  labs(fill = "Sectors", face="bold")+ 
  ylab('Water Use (Thousand m3)') + xlab("Year")+ ylim(0,200000)+ # You should be aware of ylim 
  theme(text=element_text(size=10, family="Arial"))+
  ggtitle("Top 10 sectors by water use for 2018, 2019, and with existing  year")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, face='bold'))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust = 3))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold"))
```

[image]